# Running opencart from server to localhost

Tags: localhost, opencart-3

I downloaded opencart from server and tried to run it on local host and it is not running completely. I changed the config.php file as per my localhost permissions. But it is not running can you guys please help me with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To install Opencart from your server to Localhost

1. You should add Install folder in root directory i.e yoursite's directory.
2. Empty the config files from both (remove the whole code from config files)
3. Now try to install it...

hopes it helps you